# Stopping an EC2 instance causes a new one to generate

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have setup an environment with Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk which has generated an EC2 instance. The storage is too small and I wish to increase it, so my plan was to stop the instance (termination protection is on), snapshot the volume, create a new bigger volume from the snapshot and re-attach to the instance.

The issue I'm having is that when I stop the instance, which happens successfully, another instance gets automatically generated! How do I stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the default autoscaling min group size is 1. You can set the autoscaling min and max group size to 0 using ebextensions.
Create a folder called `.ebextensions` in your app source. In this folder create a file with name `01-asg.config`. Add the following to this file. Note the file is in YAML format so indentation is important.

```
Resources:
       AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
             Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
             Properties:
                 MinSize: 0
                 MaxSize: 0
```

Zip the app source and deploy this new version to your environment. The instance should go away.

Comment: Thanks Rohit. It makes sense now, the beanstalk is making sure that an  instance is always available and generates a new one when I terminate the original instance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't manage Elastic Beanstalk instances from the EC2 console… Use the Elastic Beanstalk console.

Comment: Ryan, I might be being blind but there is really a very limited amount of options within the Elastic Beanstalk itself. As far as I can see you can't do what I described above, i.e taking snapshots, increasing the volume etc.

Comment: Forgive me. I was (perhaps overly-succinctly) answering the second part of your question. "The issue I'm having is that when I stop the instance, which happens successfully, another instance gets automatically generated! How do I stop this behavior?" Rohit Banga offered a more thorough answer than I did.